# Circleci failed downloading libvips

Tags: node.js, circleci, sharp

We have this issue for a couple of days.
nodejs version is12.16.1
we are using yarn and not npm

SHARP_DIST_BASE_URL is referring to https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/folder
where the libvips-8.7.4-linux-x64.tar.gz is saved

in the config.yml was defined:

```
working_directory: /home/faul/dev/bot-engine-ci
```

we didn't change anything on the versions/installations/aws

```
[5/5] Building fresh packages...
error /home/faul/dev/bot-engine-ci/node_modules/sharp: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)
Arguments: 
Directory: /home/faul/dev/bot-engine-ci/node_modules/sharp
Output:
info sharp Downloading ***************************************************libvips-8.7.4-linux-x64.tar.gz
/home/faul/dev/bot-engine-ci/node_modules/sharp/install/libvips.js:86
          throw new Error(`Status ${response.statusCode}`);
          ^

Error: Status 403
    at /home/faul/dev/bot-engine-ci/node_modules/sharp/install/libvips.js:86:17
    at f (/home/faul/dev/bot-engine-ci/node_modules/once/once.js:25:25)
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/home/faul/dev/bot-engine-ci/node_modules/simple-get/index.js:63:5)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:418:26)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:603:27)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:119:17)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:476:22)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:294:12)
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@5.0.5
gyp info using node@12.16.1 | linux | x64
gyp info find Python using Python version 2.7.13 found at "/usr/bin/python"
gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v12.16.1/node-v12.16.1-headers.tar.gz
gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v12.16.1/node-v12.16.1-headers.tar.gz
gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v12.16.1/SHASUMS256.txt
gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v12.16.1/SHASUMS256.txt
gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python
gyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/home/faul/dev/bot-engine-ci/node_modules/sharp/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/root/.cache/node-gyp/12.16.1/include/node/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/root/.cache/node-gyp/12.16.1',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/root/.cache/node-gyp/12.16.1/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/home/faul/dev/bot-engine-ci/node_modules/sharp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
gyp info spawn args ]
gyp info spawn make
gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
make: Entering directory '/home/faul/dev/bot-engine-ci/node_modules/sharp/build'
  TOUCH Release/obj.target/libvips-cpp.stamp
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/sharp/src/common.o
../src/common.cc:25:22: fatal error: vips/vips8: No such file or directory
 #include <vips/vips8>
                      ^
compilation terminated.
sharp.target.mk:138: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/sharp/src/common.o' failed
make: *** [Release/obj.target/sharp/src/common.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/home/faul/dev/bot-engine-ci/node_modules/sharp/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:311:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 5.13.0-1023-aws
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/faul/dev/bot-engine-ci/node_modules/sharp
gyp ERR! node -v v12.16.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.5
gyp ERR! not ok
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.

Exited with code exit status 1
CircleCI received exit code 1
```

All the issues I saw about this were from 2019, I didn't find any new post about that.
Please assist!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

in .circleci/config.yml file
we added under "Install all Dependencies":

```
   environment:
     SHARP_DIST_BASE_URL: our CDN link
```